# how to check the object and methods available for this object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm new to JavaScript, I love the `MyClass.class` and `MyClass.methods` in Ruby, are there any equivalence in JavaScript to check out the object type and methods available?

BTW the `typeof` operator seems to always return `'object'`, I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any equivalence in JavaScript to check out the object type..

The `typeof` operator does that, but it can be confusing with what it reports back.

For example, `typeof null` will tell you `'object'`, though it is not an object (though this behaviour is defined).

`typeof 'a'` will tell you `'string'`, but `typeof new String('a')` will tell you an `'object'`.

The other advantage of `typeof` operator is it will not throw a `ReferenceError` if its operand has not yet been declared.

The methods used below to determine a function can be adapted to report the correct type (though `typeof` is generally enough for primitives).

> ...and methods available?

You can view all the properties on an object with a `for ( in )` loop.

```
for (var prop in obj) {
   console.log(prop);
}
```

This will show all enumerable properties, including ones inherited/delegated. To disregard inherited properties, add this to the body of the loop...

```
if ( ! obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
   continue;
}
```

To view *methods* (properties assigned a function), you can do this...

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) || Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) != '[object Function]') {
        continue;
    }
   console.log(prop, obj[prop]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U96wc/).

If not in a multi `window` environment (i.e. not `iframe`s), you can simply use...

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) || ! (obj[prop] instanceof Function)) {
        continue;
    }
   console.log(prop, obj[prop]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht2PW/).

...or...

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) || obj[prop].constructor != Function) {
        continue;
    }
   console.log(prop, obj[prop]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HkCr/).

If you only care about methods that implement `[[Call]]` (i.e. can be invoked as a function), such as the [`RegExp` objects in older Safaris](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Regular_expressions), you can simply determine what is invokable with `typeof fn == 'function'`.

Since you mentioned Ruby, you could be completely crazy and implement Ruby's `class` (or close enough) and `methods` by augmenting `Object.prototype`, but please don't. :)

I also have an in-depth article on the [`typeof` operator in JavaScript](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-typeof).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript everything is an object and Functions are first class JavaScript Objects.

Use this snippet if you wanna know the `type` of all objects.

```
var is = {
    Null: function (a) {
        return a === null;
    },
    Undefined: function (a) {
        return a === undefined;
    },
    nt: function (a) {
        return (a === null || a === undefined);
    },
    Function: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'function') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/Function/) !== null : false;
    },
    String: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'string') ? true : (typeof (a) === 'object') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/string/i) !== null : false;
    },
    Array: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'object') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/array/i) !== null || a.length !== undefined : false;
    },
    Boolean: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'boolean') ? true : (typeof (a) === 'object') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/boolean/i) !== null : false;
    },
    Date: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'date') ? true : (typeof (a) === 'object') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/date/i) !== null : false;
    },
    HTML: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'object') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/html/i) !== null : false;
    },
    Number: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'number') ? true : (typeof (a) === 'object') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/Number/) !== null : false;
    },
    Object: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'object') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/object/i) !== null : false;
    },
    RegExp: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === 'function') ? a.constructor.toString().match(/regexp/i) !== null : false;
    }
};

var type = {
    of: function (a) {
        for (var i in is) {
            if (is[i](a)) {
                return i.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now call it like this.

```
var a= [];
var b ={};
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var d = function(){};
var e = "";
var f = 5;

alert(type.of(a)); //alerts array
alert(type.of(b)); //alerts object
alert(type.of(c)); //alerts html
alert(type.of(d)); //alerts function
alert(type.of(e)); //alerts string
alert(type.of(f)); //alerts number
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/nARdX/)

Comment: The `undefined` check should compare to `void()`. This also won't work in a multi `window` environment. Also, Firefox says a regex is a `object`. WebKit says regexes are `function`.

Comment: just showed the op how to retrieve type.of easily. :) i know the code has its bugs

Comment: Fair enough, but if code has bugs you know of, why don't you fix them? :)

Comment: @alex: because i didnt know the exact bugs. i got this earlier from a google search and stored it for future reference. i knew that undefined didn't work in my test. i didn't check with regex as i consider it my nemesis. i am putting aside starting learning regex evryday to the next day :) i tested the rest and found that OP might have a use with it. thats all. feel free to edit if you got time.